# How to Adjust MQ131 Sensor?

Tags: sensors, hardware, code-review

**The problem**

Hey. I'm trying to use the sensor Mq131 to measure some ozone data in a closed environment, but I'm having some bad time to adjust the trim in the sensor and get results in ppb. By searching on the internet I could not find any elucidative manual/instruction.

---

**My Hardware set**

As my first attempt, I've made the following wiring with the Arduino UNO and the sensor module.
[image: Wiring of the Mq131 in Arduino UNO]

Notice that my potentiometer does not have any indication of the resistance reached when spinning the potentiometer screw.

[image: Picture the sensor. Detail on potentiometer screw.]

---

**My software script**

To get the value of tension in the output from the sensor I'm using the following approach.

```
int sensor_AOUT = A1; //connected from AOUT to the sensor to A1 on the Arduino 
int sensor_DOUT = 2; //connect DOUT from sensor to Arduino pin 2 
int wartosc_AOUT; //variable for the value of AOUT 
int wartosc_DOUT; //variable for the value of DOUT 
 
void setup() { 
 Serial.begin(9600); //start the monitor serial port 
 pinMode(2, INPUT); //set pin 2 as input 
 
} 
 
void loop() { 
 
 wartosc_AOUT = analogRead(sensor_AOUT); //load values from AOUT 
 wartosc_DOUT = digitalRead(sensor_DOUT); //load values DOUT 
 
 Serial.print("D0: "); //display on serial monitor 
 Serial.print(wartosc_DOUT); 
 Serial.print(" -- A0: "); 
 Serial.println(wartosc_AOUT); 
 delay(200); //delay between consecutive readings 
 }
```

which gives me values 30 < A0 <50. How can I get a value in ppb (parts per billion) and how can I calibrate the potentiometer screw?

---

**Sensor Datasheet**

The datasheet of this sensor can be found in [this](http://www.sensorica.ru/pdf/MQ-131.pdf) link.

Comment: what do you expect the potentiometer to do? ... you will need to have the datasheet to determine the `ppb` conversion ... another way to calibrate is to compare the output against an already calibrated sensor

Comment: @jsotola I've edited the question including the datasheet of the sensor. I would expect that the potentiometer enhances the sensibility of the sensor. I don't have any other calibrated sensor here, so I can not consider this option.